# Insufficient memory causes Java threads to do things only halfway

Tags: java, multithreading

If set the JVM args to this:

```
-Xms10m -Xmx10m
```

The following programs worked fine and 1000 files with content were created.

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Test {
    public static final int COUNT = 1_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testByThread();
    }

    public static void testByThread() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                int num = write1("threadTest\\", finalI);
                System.out.println(num);
            }).start();
        }
        System.out.println("total: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }

    public static int write1(String name, int i) {
        try {
            String content = "This is the content to write into create file";
            String path = "D:\\" + name + i + ".txt";
            File file = new File(path);

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i + 1;
    }
}
```

However, if I reduce the heap size:

```
-Xms2m -Xmx2m
```

The program came to hint some exception in the console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-253" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Thread-254" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
```

And though 1000 files are created, some of them (275 files) have no content, meaning that the file size is 0kb.

I wonder why the thread just created the file but did not continue to write the content. What happened during the whole `write1(String name, int i)` process in each thread?

Comment: Its not good creating 1000 threads to write like this, but note that you don't need to use `BufferedWriter` here at all.  That may be the cause of up to 1000 x 8k buffer allocation leading to OOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you run out of memory, the OOME (`OutOfMemoryError`) will kill the current thread.  (Unless caught ... and you are not catching it.)

If the thread gets the OOME after it has opened the file and before it closes it, the file *may* be empty or partially written.

Solution: don't create 1,000 I/O threads!  It is a bad idea even when it works.

Instead, use an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread pool, and submit a task for each of the files to be created.  Tune the the thread pool to optimize performance by adjusting the pool size parameters.  (Statically via a hard coded constant or a settings file or something.)

---

Also note that if you try to do a huge number of file (or network) operations in parallel (using lots of threads) your application will saturate the network or file system I/O capacity and hit a resource bottleneck.  (Or a CPU or RAM bandwidth bottleneck.  Or you could trigger virtual memory thrashing.)

Parallelizing I/O and then saturating it doesn't help, and can actually lead to really bad outcomes.  Maybe worse that you are seeing, up to an including "breaking" the network for other users or crashing the host operating system.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77371427/139985) talks about whether or not you should be catching the OOMEs.  I think that you shouldn't ... in this use-case.

If an OOME occurs you *will have* created the partial or empty file.  The best you could do would be to delete the file and try again.  But the risk is that the OOME will occur again, and again, and again.

In addition, each time you get an OOME, that (typically) be preceded by a full garbage collection.  Doing GC's repeatedly when your heap is *nearly* full is inefficient / bad for performance.

That answer also says that you shouldn't try to catch an OOME anyway because the OOME could have caused other damage to application and runtime data structures.  This is true in the general case<sup>1</sup>, but in this specific use-case, any such damage will be limited to objects / resources that would be cleaned up by the GC anyway.  OOMEs and (in some cases SOEs) are more recoverable than other `Error` exceptions<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - You also need to worry threads that are stuck waiting for a `notify` from another thread that was killed by the OOME.  Recovering from that scenario is difficult.

2 - ... if you really understand what you are doing; e.g. see 1.</sup>

Comment: Exactly. Even writing (or even accessing) 2 different (big) files to the same disk (as in Hard-Disk, not SSD) simultaneously can drop your output speed to 10% or less, which is already catastrophic. Guess what happens if that gets even more. Now with sophisticated and huge write caches of modern OSs, this will not hit that hard on smaller files. But in some of my projects I prefer to more or less show the app's actual progress, so I limit access to each disk to 1 at a time. This does not have a real adverse effect on speed, but I can inform the user a lot better on the actual state of affairs

Comment: If using Java 21, there is `ExecutorService` for [virtual threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-BEC799E0-00E9-4386-B220-8839EA6B4F5C).

Comment: Yes ... but 1,000 virtual threads doing I/O would be almost as bad as 1,000 native threads.  You need the pool to be bounded.  Virtual vs native threads is (IMO) a minor concern for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

The main culprit that crashes most Threads is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-891" Exception in thread "Thread-871" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:88)
    at stackoverflow.threading.TestThreadOOME.write1(TestThreadOOME.java:35)
    at stackoverflow.threading.TestThreadOOME.lambda$0(TestThreadOOME.java:19)
    at stackoverflow.threading.TestThreadOOME$$Lambda$1/531885035.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:88)
    at stackoverflow.threading.TestThreadOOME.write1(TestThreadOOME.java:35)
    at stackoverflow.threading.TestThreadOOME.lambda$0(TestThreadOOME.java:19)
    at stackoverflow.threading.TestThreadOOME$$Lambda$1/531885035.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

That is the normal error stack trace of Java. Which usually tells you everything you need to know.

So this tells us, that the problem happens when we try to instantiate the `BufferedWriter`. If we look at its code, the way you call it, it will attempt to create a buffer with the size of `private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192;` bytes. As 8 KB is MUCH compared to the tiny environment you give it, this is where MOST errors will happen.

So your code first creates a `FileWriter`, which in turn creates a `FileOutputStream` which on creation will create a `FileDescriptor`, on which it calls `open()`, which creates your file on the disk (without contenty yet).

So in short: calling `new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());` will already create the file, but without contents yet.

Now, in the next step, `new BufferedWriter(fw);` will fail, and the Thread (i.e. your `write1` method) will abort. Before any data can be written to the file.

Note, that even if you extended your catch clause to `} catch (final Throwable e) {`, which COULD catch Exceptions AND Errors, this would not be enough, the problem would often still crash your thread, because the `OutOfMemoryError` is so severe that you will not be able to rely on most functions inside the JVM anymore.

Also note that the OOME CAN happen literally anywhere in your code, whenever you call `new`, even if you simply call a method, but it's usually where larger portions of the RAM are getting reserved, like `byte[]` or `char[]` or similar buffers. So if you ran your example a million times, you would probably get all different error cases.